# GXT Window AutoHide Listener

Tags: gxt

I am trying to trap the GXT Window hide event.  Below is my code, but it does not work.  The Log statement never get called.

```
myGXTWindowObject.addListener(Events.AutoHide, new Listener<WindowEvent>()
{

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(WindowEvent arg0) {
        Log.info("handle Window AutoHide event");
    }

});
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Below is how I did:

```
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        public void windowHide(WindowEvent we) {
            System.out.println("windowHide");
        }
    });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If myGXTWindowObject is of type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window, it does not actually fire the Events.AutoHide event which you are Listening for, only Events.Hide. See the events section at the end of the docs:
[com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window](http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/#com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window)